# How to properly create function that moves a shape using Zelle's 'graphics.py' program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Question 17 of Ch. 6 in Zelle's 'Programming Python' books asks for a function that takes two arguments: 'shape', and 'newCenter', which will then move, or re-draw, an existing object based on the new points provided by a mouse-click.

I've been able to figure out how to do it if I add two more parameters to the function, "myX", and "myY", so I can then subtract the difference for the move method.  What is eluding me is how to perform the same calculations using just the two parameters specified above.  Here is my code:

```
def moveTo(shape, newCenter, myX, myY):
    myShape = shape
    myNewX = newCenter.getX()
    myNewY = newCenter.getY()
    myXUpd = myNewX - myX
    myYUpd = myNewY - myY
    myShape.move(myXUpd, myYUpd)
    return myNewX, myNewY

def main():
    win = GraphWin("My Graph Win", 500, 500)
    win.setBackground("white")
    win.setCoords(0, 0, 10, 10)
    Text(Point(5, 8.5), "Please click 10 times.").draw(win)
    myPoint = win.getMouse()
    myX = myPoint.getX()
    myY = myPoint.getY()
    myCircle = Circle(myPoint, 2)
    myCircle.draw(win)

    for x in range(1, 10):
        myNewPoint = win.getMouse()
        myX, myY = moveTo(myCircle, myNewPoint, myX, myY)

    win.close()
```

Also, any general tips for streamlining, style, or structure are also appreciated as I'm a rather new Python developer.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume myCircle has some data structure that gives you access to myPoint.  So something like myCircle.myPoint.getX() would get you the x value.  As you pass myCircle to the function and its called shape in the function.  You would need shape.myPoint.getX().  However, not all shapes will have myPoints.  Really depends on the structures of the class.

Comment: @SBHayes I see what you are saying, I would probably need to reset myCircle inside the loop where I'm resetting myX and myY so that it returns the "latest" version of the circle.  And you are absolutely right that not all shapes will not have a myPoint, the Circle and Rectangle classes both do, but some of the more abstract Polygonal shapes might not.

Comment: to avoid having to reset your shape, just call move on shape instead of myShape.

Comment: @SBHayes Your idea of pulling it out of the data structure was the correct one.  Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out on my own, so anyone going through the Zelle "Python Programming" book can learn from my experience.  I just pulled the X and Y out of the shape object I was passing in, thus saving myself having to pass them in again separately.  Here is the updated code with some of the fat trimmed down.

```
def moveTo(shape, newCenter):
    oldCenter = shape.getCenter()
    myOldX, myOldY = oldCenter.getX(), oldCenter.getY()
    myNewX, myNewY = newCenter.getX(), newCenter.getY()
    moveX = myNewX - myOldX
    moveY = myNewY - myOldY
    shape.move(moveX, moveY)
    return shape

def main():
    win = GraphWin("My Graph Win", 500, 500)
    win.setBackground("white")
    win.setCoords(0, 0, 10, 10)
    Text(Point(5, 8.5), "Please click 10 times.").draw(win)
    myPoint = win.getMouse()
    myX, myY = myPoint.getX(), myPoint.getY()
    myShape = Circle(myPoint, 2)
    myShape.draw(win)

    for x in range(1, 10):
        newCenter = win.getMouse()
        myShape = moveTo(myShape, newCenter)


    win.close()
```

Comment: Nice solution.  I realized in the shower last night what I told you about modifying shape in the function wouldn't work.  Your solution is the correct way.  I was just testing you ;)

Comment: Well played sir, well played;)